# running a single scenario of a parametrized junit test in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, parameterized

I have a Parameterized junit test with several scenarios & need to be able to run just **one** of the scenarios.

I would like to do it in IntelliJ. Does anyone know how to?

Here's a code example:

Here's the collection of scenarios, the parameter and the test method:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MyTest {

   @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index}: {0}")                
   public static List<String[]> e2e_scenarios() {                  
       return  Arrays.asList(new String[][]{                       
               {"scenario 1"},                                  
               {"scneario 2"}, 
       });
   }       

   @Parameterized.Parameter       
   public String scenarioName;    

   @Test
   public void testrScenario() {
       System.out.println("running scenario " + scenarioName);
   }
}
```

I want to be able to run just a single scenario. Preferably, I would like to do than from the IntelliJ GUI or Junit Runner.

After running all the scenarios once, it is possible to right click one of them in the "run" window and run or debug just it. This solution is not ideal, because the entire suite need to run prior to being able to run just one.

Comment: I think that this is not possible because it requires a heavy load of static analysis of the code. Rerunning the test for a single set of parameters is much easier.

Comment: Occasionally, a member of the team needs to run/debug just a single scenario. This is the motivation. We used to have a method for each scenario, but they all looks like boilerplate code, so I refactored it to be a parameterized test. The only thing that is not yet supported, is running a single one.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your parameter by adding it at the end of the method name in the run/debug configuration. IntelliJ will show a warning but it will run JUnit test properly. Works for primitive types, Strings, and Enums, not sure how it will work for complex objects.

Example:

```
@Parameterized.Parameters(name = "MyEnum: {0}")
public static setParameters() {
   ...
}

Method in the configuration: testDoSomething[MyEnum: VALUE1]
```